# Network Error Related to CiviCase After Recent Upgrade to 5.8.2

Tags: drupal, upgrade, error, civicase

I am new here and not an IT person so hopefully I ask this question correctly and with enough detail.

We upgraded over the weekend from CiviCRM 4.7 to 5.8.2 (drupal) and each time I login to the system I get a Network Error message that says "Unable to reach server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."  The hosting service suspects its a bug with CiviCase and provided me with a link to the detailed error information (no site specific details): https://pastebin.com/B75LJeh0

When I look at the cases, everything looks ok with the exception that in the "Case Coordinator" column, it lists "array" instead of the user's name.

Does anyone have any ideas or info they can provide me with? Thanks!

Comment: The error is the comma just before the word FROM, but what page are you on when it comes up?

Comment: As soon as I login to the site the error message pops up.

Comment: Which page is that, e.g. is it `https://<yoursite.org>/civicrm?reset=1`, or some other url? If it's a dashboard, what items are on the dashboard? I'm not able to see the problem on a 5.8.2 system with either the cases dashlet or case dashboard so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: The page is https://<yoursite.org>/civicrm.  On my dashboard I have the two reports: an scheduled activities report and a cases report. When I remove those reports, the error does go away. Could it be because I did a language replacement of "Case Coordinator" to "Grant Manager"? That's where I see "array" listed instead of the assigned user.

Comment: Does the cases report include maybe a custom field that is no longer there? The comma in the error message suggests maybe it's expecting another field in the output but it can't find it. If you run the same report separate from the dashboard does it work?

Comment: When I run a cases report from the report section I get this message.....Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in CRM_Utils_Date::getFromTo() (line 859 of /home/<yoursite>/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Date.php).

Comment: I'm guessing now but maybe try under Administer - System Settings - Cleanup Caches.